# jQuery(document).ready shouldn't run when I submit the form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I wrote some jquery that runs when a certain page loads, and it's good. The problem is that it also runs when I submit the form, and it messes up the submission.

Is there any way to get around that?

My form: http://goinspire.com/jwrp-hotel-registration/

And the jquery file: http://goinspire.com/wp-content/themes/goinspire/js/customjqueryfunctions.js

Thanks!

Here is the part of the code that I believe is pertinent:

```
// CUSTOM JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    tripFilter = function () {
        var tripClass = '.hotel-trip select',
            hotelClass  = '.hotel-name select',
            unusedClass = '.unused-options select';
        var tripSelect = jQuery(tripClass),
           trip = tripSelect.val(),
           hotelSelect = tripSelect.parents('form').find(hotelClass);

        if (trip !== undefined && trip !== "") {
            if (trip === "none"){
                jQuery(hotelClass+" > option").each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).clone().appendTo(unusedClass);
                    jQuery(this).remove();
                }); 
            } else {
                tripnum =  trip.match(/JWRP (\d*)/)[1];

                jQuery(unusedClass+" > option").each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).clone().appendTo(hotelClass);
                    jQuery(this).remove();
                });
                jQuery(hotelClass+" > option").each(function() {
                    hotelMatch = jQuery(this).val().match(/(\d*) /);
                    if(jQuery(this).val() != "Other|"){
                        if (hotelMatch === null || hotelMatch[1] != tripnum){
                            jQuery(this).clone().appendTo(unusedClass);
                            jQuery(this).remove();
                        };
                    }else{
                        jQuery(this).appendTo(hotelClass);
                    };
                });
                jQuery(hotelClass + 'option[value="Other|"]').insertAfter(hotelClass + 'option:last-child');
                jQuery(hotelClass).val(jQuery(hotelClass + "option:first").val());
            }
        }
    }

    jQuery('.hotel-trip select').change(function(){
        tripFilter();
    });

    tripFilter();
});
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: not all jquery has to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function. just write a normal js function and put the code in there, but as j08691 said, if you're on SO, you're expected to put your code in the question, don't link it.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that fixed it; I'm going to double check now.

Comment: Nope, it's still not working. Any other ideas? Thanks!